# The shape of an $\epsilon$-neighborhood of a point in the Poincare disk model

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

What does an $\epsilon$-neighborhood of a point $x \in \mathbb{H}^{2}$ (i.e. its shape) look like on the [Poincare disk model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model) of $\mathbb{H^{2}}$ as we move it around the disk and increase $\epsilon$?

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model#Circles).

Answer (score 1):

The $\epsilon$-neighborhoods of points in $\Bbb{H}^2$ are (Euclidean) disks.

One can see this by first observing that an $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $0$ in the Poincare disk model is a disk. For the Poincare disk model of hyperbolic space, the isometries are given by the action of $\operatorname{SU}(1,1)$.

Isometries act transitively, so any point in $\Bbb{H}^2$ can be realized as the image of $0$ under some isometry, hence the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of any point can be realized as the image of the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $0$ under some element of $\operatorname{SU}(1,1)$.